# Delete set of lines between two strings in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task to read a bunch of notepad files and in each of the file, I need to delete the set of lines which are present in between the strings "dynamics" and "end dynamics" and also delete those two strings as well.

[image]

The attached image shows the part which needs to be removed, wherever it has occurred (dynamics to end dynamics – any content can be present with these two boundaries) in that text file.

```
L3.3

resizeText 1
zoomLines 0
zoomArrows 0
doLasso 1
opaqueMove 1
selectDistance 30
adjustFonts 1
doubleBuffer 1
clipping 1
nCopyAreas 0
drawTextLimit 0.5
saveObjects 1
canvasBackground #050048007800
defaultForeground #000000000000
layers 1
layerName 0 0
layerName 1 1
layerName 2 2
layerName 3 3
layerName 4 4
layerName 5 5
layerName 6 6
layerName 7 7
layerName 8 8
layerName 9 9
layerName 10 10
layerName 11 11
layerName 12 12
layerName 13 13
layerName 14 14
layerName 15 15
layerName 16 16
layerName 17 17
layerName 18 18
layerName 19 19
layerName 20 20
layerName 21 21
layerName 22 22
layerName 23 23
layerName 24 24
layerName 25 25
layerName 26 26
layerName 27 27
layerName 28 28
layerName 29 29
layerName 30 30
layerName 31 31
gend

N 0
P 0 0
T -1
R 0 0
0
    0 4 1 0
    Name #WVP
    0 1 1
!
27e
054878
-1-1-1
0
0
0
0 0
dynamics
script
//***GblSymDetails***
;DTLS; GSA_TEXT = "CIUXX"
//***ApplReplace***
//GEMTool = 1
// = ASPECTLINK
end script
end dynamics
    0 0 1920 1080 0 0
N 2
P 34.7792 181.549
T 2 21071 1 0 0
0 0
R 0 0
0
    0 0 3 0
    Name STAT5495
    0 1 1
!
27e
a5a5a5
a5a5a5
0
0
0
2 0
    0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 1 
    4
    0 12.7627
    11.5724 0
    192.874 0.255264
    185.159 12.3798
N 4
P 221.604 181.887
T 2 21071 1 0 0
0 0
R 0 0
0
    0 0 5 0
    Name STAT5496
    0 1 1
!
27e
7c7c7c
7c7c7c
0
0
0
2 0
dynamics
script
func ip_FillColor() {
return FILLCOLOR;
}
func ip_LineColor() {
return LINECOLOR;
}
func ip_TEXT() {
return TEXT;
}
func BackColor() {
return RGB(124,124,124);

}


func ForeColor() {
return RGB(124,124,124);

}












// when ...
object.background = BackColor();
object.foreground = ForeColor();
end script
end dynamics
    0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 1 
    4
    0 11.6149
    6.04944 0
    6.04944 54.445
    0 72.5933
N 6
P 81.7124 181.888
T 2 21071 1 0 0
0 0
R 0 0
0
    0 0 7 0
    Name STAT5497
    0 1 1
!
27e
616161
616161
0
0
0
2 0
dynamics
script
func ip_FillColor() {
return FILLCOLOR;
}
func ip_LineColor() {
return LINECOLOR;
}
func ip_TEXT() {
return TEXT;
}
func BackColor() {
return RGB(97,97,97);

}


func ForeColor() {
return RGB(97,97,97);

}












// when ...
object.background = BackColor();
object.foreground = ForeColor();
end script
end dynamics
    0 1 0
    0 0 0 0 1 
    72
    93.8536 5.86588
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the code below. You should be able to add code to dump all the files into a folder and DIR through them reading, stripping text and saving the output files automatically. Depending on the number of files it may or may not be time-efficient to do.

```
Sub cleantext()
Dim lineOfText As String
Dim skipLines As Boolean
'Open files for writing
Open "D:\inputfile.txt" For Input As #1
Open "D:\outputfile.txt" For Output As #2

skipLine = False
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, lineOfText
    If lineOfText = "dynamics" Then skipLines = True
    If lineOfText = "end dynamics" Then skipLines = False
    If Not skipLines And Not lineOfText = "end dynamics" Then Print #2, lineOfText
Loop
Close #1
Close #2
End Sub
```